# Use twitter bootstrap span in foreach

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap

How do you use the twitter spans within a foreach loop?

This is my code:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <?foreach ($photos as $photo) { ?>
        <div class="span4">
            stuff
        </div>
    <? }?>
</div>
```

But the problem is the 4th output (which is now on the 2nd row) is off center - due to the margin/padding to the left.

I'm trying to avoid having to add a counter and manually insert a new 'row' after each 3rd loop - surely there is a cleaner way via bootstrap/css?

Comment: `.span4:nth-child(3n+1) {}` maybe?

Comment: That sounds good - how would I use it?

Comment: Nth-child functions as (3n+1), or (3 x n) + 1, where n increments. So 3n+1 would affect elements #1, #4, #7, etc.

Comment: It's just CSS, so right in your main CSS file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using CSS3's nth-child selector, you can target elements using math.

```
.span4:nth-child(3n+1) {
    /* CSS here */
}
```

The 3n+1 is a math function where n is incrementing by 1, so it would target elements #1 (3x0 + 1), #4 (3x1 + 1), #7 (3x2 + 1), etc.

Comment: .span4:nth-child(3n+1) {margin-left:0px;} works perfectly - thanks